# C#, function to replace all html special characters with normal text characters

Tags: c#, html-entities

I have characters incoming from an xml template for example:

```
&amp; &gt;
```

Does a generic function exist in the framework to replace these with their normal equivalents?

Answer (score 69):

You want to use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx).:

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string.

Comment: I have a problem with this and scandinavian characters. It does decode ex. `%20` to blank space, but `%F8` which should be an `ø` is just shown as some sort of ascii question mark figure. Any tips?

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes the text has parts that has been doubly encoded.

For example: `"Lorem Ipsum&amp;#x0D;&#10;&#32;&#32;&#32;-&#32;Blah"`

This may help with that:

```
public static string RecursiveHtmlDecode(string str) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) return str;  
    var tmp = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str);
    while (tmp != str)
    {
        str = tmp;
        tmp = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str);
    }
    return str; //completely decoded string
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this helps: `WebUtility.HtmlDecode("");`