# Cannot remove html from string

Tags: c#, regex

I downloaded some data from a site, and I got this string: `Guangzhou R&amp;F`, as you can see within the string I have also `amp;` but the correct string (displayed on the site) is: Guangzhou R&F.

So I'm trying to remove that string using `Regex`, the expression I wrote is this:

```
public static string RemoveHtml(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
}
```

the problem is that the `Regex` expression doesn't remove the `amp;` what I did wrong?

Comment: &amp; is the HTML encoding for an ampersand (&). It will render as &.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#, function to replace all html special characters with normal text characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720684/c-function-to-replace-all-html-special-characters-with-normal-text-characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to manually replace or remove HTML, read about [Character encodings in HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

Here is the solution what you need:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
```