# How can I use C# to search an XML file for specific words?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm very new to C# and XML files in general, but currently I have an XML file that still has some html markup in it (&amp, ;quot;, etc.) and I want to read through the XML file and remove all of those so it becomes easily readable. I can open and print the file to the console with no issue, but I'm stumped trying to search for those specific strings and remove them.

Comment: maybe `String.IndexOf` or `String.Replace` is what you're searching for?

Comment: Looks like you mean html markup when talking about "script syntax". This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720684/c-function-to-replace-all-html-special-characters-with-normal-text-characters

Comment: Can you present a small sample input file and what you would want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to put all the words you want to remove into an array, and then use the `Replace` method to replace them with empty strings:

```
var xmlFilePath = @"c:\temp\original.xml";
var newFilePath = @"c:\temp\modified.xml";

var wordsToRemove = new[] {"&amp", ";quot;"};

// Read existing xml file
var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(xmlFilePath);

// Remove words
foreach (var word in wordsToRemove)
{
    fileContents = fileContents.Replace(word, "");
}

// Create new file with words removed
File.WriteAllText(newFilePath, fileContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netcore-3.1

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string.

```
// Encode the string.
        string myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);

        Console.WriteLine($"HTML Encoded string is: {myEncodedString}");
        StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();

        // Decode the encoded string.
        HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);

        string myDecodedString = myWriter.ToString();
        Console.Write($"Decoded string of the above encoded string is: {myDecodedString}");
```

Your string is html encoded, probably for transmission over network. So there is a built in method to decode it.